# How to Split Querystring in JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split the value from querystring using window.location.search after that I am getting the below value like

```
'?path=/dev/dev-alert-banner--alert-banner&args=alertBannerType:dark'
```

I tried to use like window.location.search.split('/').pop() but i am getting the value like  `dev-alert-banner--alert-banner&args=alertBannerType:dark`

how can i get the value like
`dev-alert-banner--alert-banner`
using JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the built-in [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) API to parse the QS for you - then you can do split with pop:

```js
const value = '?path=/dev/dev-alert-banner--alert-banner&args=alertBannerType:dark';

const params = new URLSearchParams(value);

console.log(params.get("path").split("/").pop());
```